# Tikz \draw with controls with limited range

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I limit the drawing of a curve defined with \draw .. controls .. to a specific range?

Example: \draw is defined up till x=9, but I would like to stop the \draw for x>=8

```
 \draw[->] 
  (3,1) .. controls (3.75,1.4) and (4.25,1.4) ..
  (5,1) .. controls (5.75,0.6) and (6.25,0.6) ..
  (7,1) .. controls (7.75,1.4) and (8.25,1.4) ..
  (9,1);
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You'd probably need to clip it. Unlike metapost I don't think you can get sub paths out of a tikz path.

Comment: Besides clipping, you could [shorten the curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/652865) or even use a decoration for that. (There's also [`\pgfpathcurvebetweentime`](https://tikz.dev/base-paths#\pgfpathcurvebetweentime) on the lower level.) But I think the easiest following your instruction (x≥8) would be the `\clip`.

Comment: Your drawing looks like a sine curve. There might be a better option drawing this with `sin` and `cos` path operations.

Comment: Thx @Qrrbrbirlbel . Indeed very similar to sin and cos, and only minor difference. Will yield simpler solution.
Thanks for showing the "shorten" feature. New to me.

Answer (score 2):

In your simple case – because you want to stop the curve exactly at half the length *and* time – you could use the PGF level command `\pgfpathcurvebetweentime` which has no proper TikZ path operation.

Instead of

```
(7,1) .. controls (7.75,1.4) and (8.25,1.4) .. (9,1)
```

you need to write

```
(7,1) to[shorten controls={0 .. (7.75,1.4) and (8.25,1.4) .. .5}] (9,1)
```

where the curve is only drawn between times `0` and `1 - .5`. (If both are `0` everything of the curve will be drawn.)

You can't place nodes along that path (but I believe that can be implemented pretty easily).

For more complex situation, I think the best would be to use the [`spath3` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3).

I've also added a very similar curve with `sin` and `cos` which doesn't give the exact same curve but might be good enough in your case.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  shorten controls/.code args={#1..#2..#3}{
    \pgfutil@in@{and}{#2}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@\expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
      \else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@shorten controls/.@cmd}#1..#2..#3\pgfeov}
    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@shorten controls/.@cmd}#1..#2and#2..#3\pgfeov}%
  },
  @shorten controls/.style args={#1..#2and#3..#4}{
    to path={
      \pgfextra
        \pgfpathcurvebetweentime{#1}{1-(#4)}
          {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)}
          {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#2}
          {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#3}
          {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)}%
      \endpgfextra
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dashed]
\draw[->, red, dash phase=3pt] 
  (3,1) .. controls (3.75,1.4) and (4.25,1.4) ..
  (5,1) .. controls (5.75,0.6) and (6.25,0.6) ..
  (7,1) to[shorten controls={0 .. (7.75,1.4) and (8.25,1.4) .. .5}]
  (9,1);
\draw[->, blue] 
  (3,1) sin ++(1,.3) cos ++(1,-.3) sin ++(1,-.3) cos ++(1,.3) sin ++(1,.3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz\draw[->] 
  (3,1) .. controls (3.75,1.4) and (4.25,1.4) ..
  (5,1) .. controls (5.75,0.6) and (6.25,0.6) ..
  (7,1) to[shorten controls={0 .. (7.75,1.4) and (8.25,1.4) .. .5}]
  (9,1);
\tikz\draw[->] 
  (3,1) sin ++(1,.3) cos ++(1,-.3) sin ++(1,-.3) cos ++(1,.3) sin ++(1,.3);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's also `\tikz\draw[->] plot[smooth, domain=0:10] (\x/2+3, 1+.3*sin(\x*45);` but that's a bit too much.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirblbel thx. Really like your last solution.
Small correction. Should be `\draw[->] plot[smooth, domain=0:10] ({\x/2+3}, {1+0.4*sin(\x*45)})`