# Drawing a loop with two different line types using TikZ-Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to draw a diagram for an interacting field theory. The diagram essentially just needs to consist of a loop connected to two external lines. The problem is that I need the loop to be made up of a dashed and solid line. So far, I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- [out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm] b -- c,
};

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

I need the right-half of the loop to be dashed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can superimpose another `dash pattern` over the `scalar` option (which is equivalent to `dashed`. You need to adjust the pattern, however, in order to have exactly the left half of the loop drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- [out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm, scalar, postaction={draw, dash pattern=on 1.5cm off 1.5cm}] b -- c,
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A maybe more elegant approach would be to use decorations to re-draw the first half of the loop path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{draw first half}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width={\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength/2}, next state=final]{
        \decoration{curveto}
    }
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- [out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm, scalar, postaction={decorate, draw, decoration={draw first half}}] b -- c,
};

\end{document}
```

A variation of this approach would be to include the dash pattern in the decoration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{half dashed}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width={\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength/2}, next state=final]{
        \decoration{curveto}
        \afterdecoration{
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{
        \beforedecoration{
            \pgfsetdash{{3pt}{3pt}}{0pt}
        }
        \decoration{curveto}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- [out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm, decorate, decoration={half dashed}] b -- c,
};

\end{document}
```

The output of these two code snippets look the same as above.

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Your first approach could be done in one path with `dash pattern=on 1.5cm off 3pt on 3pt off 3pt … on 3pt off 3pt` which gets annoying to write. (Though, we could write a macro that helps repeat stuff.) The `draw first half` decoration is much more simpler. :)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I needed to dive into the decoration stuff first. It should actually also be possible to use just a decoration to continue the dash pattern after the fully-drawn part of the path ...

Comment: Have you tried a second state with `\pgfsetdash{3pt}{3pt}\decoration{curve to}`? Could be that you have to imitate the dash pattern with the decoration, though.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, this works! However, one needs to add `\afterdecoration{ \pgfusepath{stroke} }` probably to tell PGF to draw several individual segments.

Answer (score 4):

1. A dirty (?) trick to use [`\pgfpathcurvebetweentime`](https://tikz.dev/base-paths#%5Cpgfpathcurvebetweentime) which I [recently used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657040/16595) in a different context but I don't want to mess with the `to` paths that handle the whole `out` and `in` stuff.

   `\pgfpathcurvebetweentime` uses `\pgfpathcurveto` internally which is why we need to restore it right away again.

   This also draws the path twice, one for the first half and another time for the second half but we need to specify it twice in the code (which is why I defined a key for the **l**oop **a**bove a node).
2. Same as 2. but with its own `graphs` key that may help remove redundancy.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfpathcurveto@orig\pgfpathcurveto
\tikzset{
  curve from/.code args={#1 to #2}{%
    \let\pgfpathcurveto@orig\pgfpathcurveto
    \def\pgfpathcurveto{\let\pgfpathcurveto\pgfpathcurveto@orig
      \pgfpathcurvebetweentime{#1}{#2}{\tikz@timer@start}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout,
  la/.style={out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm}]{
  a -- [scalar] b [dot]
  -- [la, curve from=0 to .5] b
  -- [la, curve from=.5 to 1, scalar] b
  -- c,
};
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout,
  la/.style={out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm}][
  /tikz/graphs/halfsies/.style n args={6}{% #1 = start, #2 = target,
    % #3 = common, #4 = "half"way point, #5 = first half, #6 = second half
    parse={#1 -- [#3,curve from=0 to #4, #5] #2;
           #1 -- [#3,curve from=#4 to 1, #6] #2;}}]{
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- c,
  {[halfsies=bb{la}{.5}{}{scalar}]};
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
half dashed/.style={
draw=none,
postaction={draw, dashed, decoration={curveto, post=moveto, post length=1/2*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate},
postaction={draw, decoration={curveto, pre=moveto, pre length=1/2*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate},
},
}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- [scalar] b [dot] -- [out=125, in=55, loop, min distance=2cm, half dashed] b -- c,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: Line and loop with left side dashed]

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this is possible! This is essentially the same I did, but much more elegantly, sice you directly use available option. Great!

Comment: Thanks. Your `\pgfdeclaremetadecoration` with no redraw also has its advantages. -it draws everything in one go. It is not always possible to use a `preaction` and the path does not always survive for a `postaction`