# Draw rotated self-energy of electron on an oblique line TikZ-Feynman

Tags: loops, tikz-feynman

I have to draw a diagram for radiative corrections on an external field, but I would like to make half-loops for self-energy of electron on the slanted fermionic lines (see figure and code).
I tried this but it doesn't seem to have any effect. There is nothing on the documentation. Could anyone help me?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{feynman}
          \vertex (a) ;
          \vertex[below right= of a] (b);
          \vertex[above right= of b] (c);
          \vertex[crossed dot, below= of b] (d) {};
          \diagram* {
                (a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (c);
                (b) -- [boson] (d);
          };
          \draw [boson, half left] ($(b)!0.2!(c)$) -- ($(b)!0.8!(c)$);
     \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is it possibile to add momentum for this half loop?

EDIT:

https://www.overleaf.com/8134191135krhdbksyvxpg

the idea is to draw these

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable. This is a LaTeX forum, so you should describe what is causing you problems without referring to the physics behind it. You could make a hand drawing of your desired/expected output.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Finally somebody that write "You could make a hand drawing of your desired/expected output." ;-)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/659637) since “half loop” is the only thing I understood.

Comment: Maybe also [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639726) or [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657029).

Comment: I added the link and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `--` to draw a straight path, you could use the tikz `arc` path:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex 

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{feynman}
          \vertex (a) ;
          \vertex[below right= of a] (b);
          \vertex[above right= of b] (c);
          \vertex[crossed dot, below= of b] (d) {};
          \diagram* {
                (a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (c);
                (b) -- [boson] (d);
          };
          \draw [boson] ($(b)!0.2!(c)$) arc[start angle=235, end angle=35, radius=12pt] node[midway,above] {k} ($(b)!0.8!(c)$);
     \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the Overleaf with your code, and I want to use momentum attribute to specify the momentum verse, but I don't understand why appears 3 arrows, instead 1